# fatal: bad config line 3 in file C:/Users/13472/.gitconfig

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I accidentally deleted my GitConfig file and I'm getting this error.
fatal: bad config line 3 in file C:/Users/13472/.gitconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please paste the contents of the file.  It could be something as simple as spacing or line endings (the file should have \n or line feeds as the line endings).

```
[user]
    name = ******
    email = *******.com
    signingKey = ""
[core]
    autocrlf = false
[http]
    sslbackend = schannel
    cookiefile = %USERPROFILE%\\.gitcookies
[filter "lfs"]
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
[gpg]
    program = gpg
[commit]
    gpgSign = false
[tag]
    forceSignAnnotated = false
```

Comment: "*Every indent in the file should be a tab charcter - not spaces.*" Not true — Git allows to mix tabs and spaces freely. See [my `.gitconfig`](https://phdru.name/Software/dotfiles/gitconfig.html) as an example; works for me perfectly.

Comment: Good point- I just grabbed the one from my windows machine - I removed the incorect statement.